# How to get list of all Kafka topics in a cluster along with partition number using JAVA

Tags: java, api, apache-kafka

I am working on a problem which requires me to fetch a list of all Kafka topics present in a cluster and also get their corresponding partition number. 
I know that this can be done through `kafka-topics.sh` command which implements `TopicCommand.scala`, but I need to implement this logic in  Java. 
I am working with Kafka 0.10.0 and looking for an API which can help me do the same. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

you can list the topics in the server with the provided consumer method listTopics(); like this:

```
Map<String, List<PartitionInfo> > topics;

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "1.2.3.4:9092");
props.put("group.id", "test-consumer-group");
props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
topics = consumer.listTopics();
```

checkout these [examples](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=kafka.api.TopicMetadata) too!

Comment: the examples are irrelevant for version 0.10.0 .since topics metadata is stored and managed in a dedicated topic in Kafka, unlike 0.8 where they've used zookeeper for the job.
but the way you've suggested is the easiest way nevertheless! you've earned a point!!!